# How can I make underscore available in the console?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I import it as such and verify it is there.

```
// test
import _ from 'underscore';
console.log(_);
```

It correctly logs to the console, but when I'm in the console and type

`_`

I get

`_ is not defined`

Comment: What build system are you using (if any)? I suppose you could use something like `window._ = _`

Comment: That's the whole purpose of modules, they don't pollute the global scope, so anything you declare inside the module is not accessible from outside it

Answer (score 2):

Assign it to `window`:

```
import _ from 'underscore';
window._ = _;
```

In the console you can access it via `window._` or just '_'.

For node, assign it to global:

```
global._ = _;
```

Comment: Shouldn't need the `window.` prefix in the console

Comment: All variables in the global scope are automatically attached to the `window` object, as well as those referenced from the global scope.

Comment: Whoa, what did you do to your answer?

Comment: Edited it. You were right, no need to assign to `window._`.

Comment: No, you most certainly need to **assign** it to `window`, you just don't need `window._` in the console, just `_` will suffice